# How to edit word document attachment using web form in Lotus notes

Tags: javascript, ms-word, lotus-notes

I have a client application now where users open word documents using ms word and save their changes. Now I am going to create a web application with familiar features. I would like to open the word documents in word online and save their changes back to lotus notes document. How we can achieve this? I don't have any clue where I need to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways, but not *in* a web form unfortunately:

- You can copy the file to Microsoft OneDrive, Dropbox or Google Docs, and use their Office-tools
- There are other packages that you can install on your server that allow your users to manipulate .docx files
- Actually, we use Swing Software in our web application to download and upload Word files from a Notes database so the user can modify the file on their PC (using Word or Libre/OpenOffice). That may not exactly match your requirements, because Word has to be installed locally.